# Is it possible to get Code Completion (Intellisense) in VSCode for Python bindings around a C library (Specifically pydrake)

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, cpython, drake

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the `pydrake` [library](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/index.html), which is python bindings around a C++ library called [Drake](https://drake.mit.edu/). I installed the library with `pip` inside a `virtualenv` and am tinkering with it in VSCode. Unfortunately, I can't get code completion for most symbols, which makes it kind of difficult to know:

- What symbols are in each (sub)module
- What args each function takes and returns

My current work flow has been to look through the C++/Python API online, which works but is a little cumbersome.

I tried to edit the `settings.json` with:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/",
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/lib/", 
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/common/",
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/manipulation/"
  ...
],
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/",
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/lib/", 
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/common/",
  "${workspaceFolder}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/manipulation/"
  ...
]
```

That was based on comments from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/7736#issuecomment-537620794, since those folders contain the cpython `.so` files. That didn't work for me.

Is it possible to get intellisense for this?

Other details in case they matter:

- Ubuntu 20.04 5.15.0-48-generic
- VSCode version: 1.71.2 74b1f979648cc44d385a2286793c226e611f59e7

  - Python extension version: v2022.14.0
- drake version: `drake==1.8.0`

Comment: PyLance uses `.pyi` files, they only contain the class/method declarations and doc strings. I don't know if you can define a location with user defined `.pyi` files

Comment: hm, the `pydrake` python package had no output for `tree -f | grep .pyi`, so I guess that's not an option for this package anyway?

Comment: you can create `.pyi` files by passing the source files through a filter, but you first need to find if you can add custom pyi files to pylance with a simple test file

Comment: It seems like according to jwnimmer-tri, adding `.pyi` is the strategy, but generating them is non-trivial. Looks like I'll have to wait for updates for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16987.  It's a work in progress.

As of today (2022-Sep-26), the `pydrake` library does not yet provide `*.pyi` files for VSCode autocomplete.

In general you can try to run tools like `stubgen` to produce the `*.pyi` files automatically from the native `*.so` files and then use those for autocomplete, but for `pydrake` those tools don't understand our templates yet, so the results are not terribly useful.

In the meantime, a Jupyter-based editor (e.g., Deepnote) *does* generally autocomplete the native code correctly.  It's only VSCode's virus-protection posture of not loading native code for auto-complete that's getting in your way.

Comment: Ah, i read through that issue, i guess the problem is kinda complex because of all the templating. I'll keep my eye on the development, thanks!